# Можно ли лимитировать вызов Action во времени?

Tags: c#, action

Можно ли сделать так, что бы Invoke не приводил к инвоку екшна если не прошло, скажем, 100ms?

Ожидаемое поведение:

- Делается инвок каждую 1мс на протяжении 101мс
- Должны сработать 1 и 101

Ожидаемое поведение 2:

- делается инвок каждую 1мс на протяжении 50мс
- должен сработать 1й и 50й инвок. 50й на 101й секунде.

Comment: это называется throttle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо Grundy

1. в шарпе нету родной реализации throttle
2. Зато есть в Reactive библиотеках, например Rx
3. Но так же можно реализовать и собственную реализацию. Например: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37795140/4423545